# Remove border-radius from Bootstrap 4 breadcrumb - Sass

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4

In Bootstrap 4 there is a Sass varaible called `$enable-rounded` which

> "Enables predefined `border-radius` styles on various components."

(https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/theming/#sass-options)

I have a requirement to remove the rounded corners on the [Breadcrumb component](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/breadcrumb/), but I don't want to remove it from any other components. Therefore I can't use `$enable-rounded` to do what I need.

However, I don't know what the optimal way to do this is.

The Sass for `_breadcrumb.scss` contains this:

```
.breadcrumb {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: $breadcrumb-padding-y $breadcrumb-padding-x;
    margin-bottom: $breadcrumb-margin-bottom;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: $breadcrumb-bg;

    @include border-radius($border-radius);
}
```

How do I override `@include border-radius($border-radius);` without modifying `_breadcrumb.scss`?

All of the CSS for my app is condensed into 1 file (`app.css`) which is built from a Sass file (`app.scss`) which first includes the relevant Bootstrap 4 Sass files. So I could do something like this:

```
// app.scss
@import breadcrumb;
@import // other_bootstrap_sass_files


// CSS specific to my app
.breadcrumb {
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

This seems a bit too similar to Bootstrap **3** where you had to override what you didn't want.

Is there a smarter way to do this with Sass for Bootstrap 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that for your specific case where you want only breadcrumbs without border-radius and all other components still have it, your only solution is doing like you mentioned in your question:

> `.breadcrumb {
>       border-radius: 0;
>   }`
>
> This seems a bit too similar to Bootstrap 3 where you had to override what you didn't want.

Personally I dont't see any other solution, only because you don't want to edit the original `_breadcrumb.scss`

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to edit `_breadcrumb.scss` because if I update Bootstrap my changes would be overwritten. That's really what the question is getting at.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the _variables.scss file, you can see all the variables that are set with !default - think of this as a preferences file. When the SCSS is compiled, your new values are swapped for the default values without having to overwrite the CSS.

Seems like `$breadcrumb-border-radius: $border-radius !default;` is what you want.

Two ways of resetting that value:

1) **Make a copy** of the _variables.scss file and place it in your project directory (I like changing the name to, say, _myvariables.scss ), look for that variable, remove the !default and change it to `$breadcrumb-border-radius: 0;` 
**OR**
 2) Make a file, say _myvariables.scss, that contains `$breadcrumb-border-radius: 0;` (and any other default values you want to change later on).

Next, import that new file **BEFORE** your bootstrap scss. In your example that would be your app.scss file:

```
// app.scss
@import myvariables.scss;  //no underscore because it's a partial
@import // other_bootstrap_sass_files including the breadcrumb component
```

Now, when the SCSS is compiled, the breadcrumb radius will be set to 0 without changing anything else or overwriting css.